# published message from cloud spring code to rabbitmq not being queued

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-task

publishing a msg from my cloud spring code to rabbitmq not being added to the rabbitmq  queue, i have a sink app that creates the rabbitmq Exchange and Queue , that is working fine.
next im using postman  post some arguments, this payload is being sent to a Controller that publish the Request thru below code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.launcher.TaskLaunchRequest;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class TaskProcessor {

@Autowired
private Source source;

public void publishRequest(String payload) {


    String url="maven://com.BBG.spring.task.text:"
            + "BBG-Spring-task-text-Validation:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT";

//arg for this test are string seperated by ,

    List<String> input= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(payload.split(",")));

    TaskLaunchRequest request = new TaskLaunchRequest(url,input,null,null,null);

    System.out.println("Created task request");

    GenericMessage<TaskLaunchRequest> message=new GenericMessage<>(request);

            this.source.output().send(message);


}


}


application properties

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
server.port=8082
spring.rabbitmq.broker-url=tcp://127.0.0.1:5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=tasktopic
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.task=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.stream=DEBUG
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.BBG.spring.task.sinc</groupId>
<artifactId>BBG-Spring-task-intake-rabbmq</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>BBG-Spring-task-intake-rabbmq</name>
<description>task in take </description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: application properties  :

    spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
    server.port=8082
spring.rabbitmq.broker-url=tcp://127.0.0.1:5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
    spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=tasktopic
    logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.task=DEBUG
    logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.stream=DEBUG

Comment: Don't use comments for more information; edit the question instead.

Comment: You need to show the `application.properties` for the sink application.

Comment: Your application properties are configuring an `input` destination but you are binding an `output`.